# Recursive Backtracking Puzzle

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, backtracking, recursive-backtracking

Using JAVA, I need to read in a text file containing an n by n table like this (although size may vary):

0110
1000
1001
0010

Assume that n is a number of people.  The table describes the relationship between a person(row) and another person(col).  If the table value is 1, the two are friends; if 0, they are not friends.  For example, (0,1) is 1; therefore, 1 and 2 are friends. I need to assign a letter out of a given number of letters (in the case of this specific table: 2) to each person in the table.  If two people are friends, they must receive a different letter.  People are not considered friends with themselves. Using RECURSIVE BACKTRACKING I need to find a solution to this puzzle and print it or determine that no solution is possible.

EDIT: Friends of friends are not considered friends unless explicitly stated in the table.  For instance, in this table, 1 is friends with 2 and 3; however 2 and 3 are not friends. 1 and 3 are friends, and 3 and 4 are friends, but 1 and 4 are not friends.  I should also note that my numbering here is natural whereas in practice the table indices begin at 0.

I am not sure where to begin with this problem.  I do realize that the tables have a line of symmetry from (0,0) to (n,n) because if (1,2) are friends (2,1) are also friends and no one is a friend of themselves thus (n,n) will always be 0.

EDIT: To show it visually, it seems to me that only the bold information is required to solve the problem.

0   **110**
10   **00**
100    **1**
0010

It seems plausible to always assign person 1 the letter A, then look through the row and assign a different letter to places with a value of 1. I am not sure how to do this exactly and it is not necessary to assign 2 and 3 different letters at this point (backtracking will deal with that later).

EDIT: I can use the following to assign a random number to a person (which will later be converted to a letter). That number can then be added to an exclusion list which will exclude these numbers from being assigned to people within a row with the value 1 (friends).

```
public static int getRandomWithExclusion(Random rnd, int start, int end, List<Integer> exclude) {
    int random = start + rnd.nextInt(end - start + 1 - exclude.size());
    for (int ex : exclude) {
        if (random < ex) {
            break;
        }
        random++;
    }
    return random;
```

EDIT:

I have this code so far; however, I cannot seem to find out how to do it using backtracking.  Also, I am not sure this will work on larger tables.  It seems to me that I need to revise my exclusion implementation.

```
    public static void assignLetter(int[][] table, int number_of_letters) {
    int[] assignments = new int[table.length];
    Random rnd = new Random();
    List<Integer> exclude = new ArrayList<>();
    // Person 1 is always assigned 1
    assignments[0]= 1;
    // Add 1 to exclusion list
    exclude.add(1);
    int row;
    int col;
    int nextAssignment;

    // Loop through each row
    for(row = 0; row <= table.length; row++) {
        //Loop through each column in each row
        for (col = row + 1; col < table.length; col++) {
            // If column value in row 1 equals 1, assigned number cannot be 1
            if (table[row][col] == 1) {
                // Generate random number within parameters excluding 1
                nextAssignment = getRandomWithExclusion(rnd, 1, number_of_letters, exclude);
                assignments[col] = nextAssignment;
            }
            // If column value in row 1 equals 0, assign person any number within parameters
            if (table[row][col] == 0 && row == 0) {
                // Generate random number within parameters, no exclusions
                nextAssignment = rnd.nextInt(number_of_letters) + 1;
                assignments[col] = nextAssignment;
            }
            // If a value in a subsequent row is 1 and the corresponding assignments are equal,
            // the assignments must be altered per the specifications
            if (table[row][col] == 1 && row > 0 && assignments[row] == assignments[col]) {
                // If the exclude list is equal to the number of letters, there is no solution
                if (exclude.size() == number_of_letters) {
                    System.out.println("There is no solution");
                }
                // If the value in row 1 of the table is not 1, it can be assigned 1
                if (table[0][col] != 1) {
                    nextAssignment = 1;
                    assignments[col] = nextAssignment;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < assignments.length; i++) {
        int person = i + 1;
        int letterNum = assignments[i];
        char[] alphaArray = new char[]{'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J',
                'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};
        char letter = alphaArray[letterNum-1];
        System.out.println(person + " : " + letter);
    }
}
```

Do you have any suggestions that could help set me on the right path?

Thank you!

Comment: Should the "0110 1000 1001 0010" be formatted as a square?

Comment: Yes, I am sorry for that. I have made the necessary corrections.  Thank you.

Comment: `If two people are friends, they must receive a different letter.` I think you left out an important condition: *friendship is transitive*, if *x friend-of y* and *y friend-of z* then *x friend-of z* . If not, there  is no really apply for recursion.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  The friendships in this case are not transitive, only undirected(friendship goes both ways).  In the table provided, 1 is friends with 2 and 3, but 2 and 3 are not friends.

Comment: @PeterMmm Why can't a friend of a friend be an enemy?  If they're not declared as friends, I wouldn't say they're friends

Comment: @PeterMmm Recursive backtracking is required because friendships are NOT transitive.  When assigning letters to people in row 1, you can only do so in reference to person 1 (whose friendships are shown in row 1).  You can assign person 1 the letter A, and B to persons 2, 3 and 4 which is perfectly fine when only looking at row 1.  But, when analyzing the entire table, we find that at row 3, person 3 is friends with person 4 (column 4), thus the rules are broken ( 3 and 4 cannot both have B because they are friends) and we must backtrack and find another solution for 3 or 4.

Comment: In the given case, the solution is simple (There are only 2 letters, person 1 is assigned A which means persons 2 and 3 must be assigned B, leaving A as the only option for person 4 because 3 and 4 must have different letters) but with much larger tables, many backtracks will be required.